# Sass doesn't import angular material checkbox theme

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

The problem is that when I specify imports in SCSS file and define my custom theme I don't see styles for checkbox except for those for typography.

My SCSS file

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-cyan, 600);
$app-accent: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 900);
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

@include mat-checkbox-theme($app-theme);
```

After attaching styles to my page I don't the actual checkbox and only see its label. There is no error or warning in console.

I also tried to place `@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);` but that didn't do any work either.

---

Ended up with that Angular Material keeps checkbox styles inside the component and not exporting it in SCSS

Answer (score 0):

Try including your mat-core() after angular-material-theme;